# Building Variable Names with Concatenate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that takes optional arguments in pairs: firstRange_1, secondRange_2; firstRange_2, secondRange_2; etc.

For each optional argument I need to execute a series of statements if the argument is passed to the function.

For example

```
dim firstRange_1 as range
dim secondRange_1 as range
dim firstRange_2 as range
dim secondRange_2 as range
etc.

dim firstCell_1 as string
dim lastCell_1 as string
dim firstCell_2 as string
dim lastCell_2 as string
etc.

If IsMissing(firstRange_1) = False Then
    firstCell_1 = secondRange_1.Cells(1,1).Address
    lastCell_1 = secondRange_1.Cells(secondRange_1.Rows.Count, secondRange_1.Rows.Count)
End if

if IsMissing(firstRange_2) = False Then
    firstCell_2 = secondRange_2.Cells(1,1).Address
    lastCell_2 = secondRange_2.Cells(secondRange_2.Rows.Count, secondRange_2.Rows.Count)
End If
```

Is it possible to "build" (sorry if the terminology isn't correct, I'm not yet experienced in programming or vba) the variables on the fly?

for example a loop like

```
For n=1 to 100
    If IsMissing(firstRange_ & "n") = False Then
        firstCell_ & "n" = secondRange_ & "n".Cells(1,1).Address
        lastCell_ & "n" = secondRange_ & "n".Cells(secondRange_ & "n".Rows.Count, secondRange_ & "n".Rows.Count)
    End If
Next
```

Edit:

See my comments to Branislav Kollár for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to rewrite the function to use **[ParamArrays (see the "Using an Indefinite Number of Arguments" section)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)**. Something like this:
 `myFunction(ParamArray userRanges()) As Range'or whatever Data Types you need`

This way, you could use the `LBound` and `UBound` functions to see how many arguments were passed into function, leaving the necessity to check if they are missing.

For example you can create a *2 new arrays inside the function* (not the argument array) for determining the first and last cells of each argument range. *This is not the only way, you can use 2D arrays or put everything into one array. This is just one way.*

```
Function myFunction(ParamArray userRanges()) As Range

        Dim firstCell() As Range
        Dim lastCell() As Range

        ReDim firstCell(UBound(userRanges))
        ReDim lastCell(UBound(userRanges))

        For x = 0 To UBound(userRanges)
            Set firstCell(x) = userRanges(x).Range("A1")
            Set lastCell(x) = firstCell_1(x).Offset(userRanges(x).Rows.Count - 1, userRanges(x).Columns.Count - 1)
        Next x

'other code to actually do something with the cells
'...    
End Function
```

Try this, if you have any trouble, please let us know.
One more link to learn about this [Understanding the ParamArray](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml)

### Edit 1

Based on comment from OP, I rewritten the code, so that now each input range `userRanges` will have `firstCell` and `lastCell` stored in appropriate arrays. I didn't realize the limitation of my previous post before.

The only think to keed in mind now, is that the index `0` is first range; `1` is second range; `2` is third range; etc.
Or you can use `Option Base 1` to make it more naturally indexed, but that is not recommended for some reason.

Comment: In my actual implementation there are a lot more than two of the first/lastCell_n and I don't see a way around manually defining all of them with this method.

Comment: This looks good, I'm trying to apply it to my problem now. I also have an integer associated with each item in userRanges(). Specifically I need to run a loop n number of times for each item in userRanges() where n is an integer associated with the item. Would it be possible to populate an array with these integers? The range that these integers come from are disjoint as are the ranges in userRanges().

Comment: @learningAsIGo It is possible to combine the *ParamArray argument* with other arguments. The *ParamArray argument* must be the last of all arguments passed into function and I think there can be only one. However it is possible to create a new range argument, where the integers ("n") will be stored (using ctrl or shift and selecting cells, you can create one range with all the integers) and combine these with the *userRanges* using some `For Each oneN in allN.cells`

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically name variables, but you can use Arrays. They are stupid powerful, so it's worth learning about them.

Essentially you will make 2 arrays. One for your input (variable1_n) and one of your outputs (output_1_n).

```
Dim inputArray(1 to 100) as String 'or whatever type these are supposed to be
Dim outputArray(1 to 100) as Range 'perhaps these are ranges?

For i = 1 to 100
    Set outputArray(i) = function(inputArray(i))
Next i
```

Now you have an array full of ranges!

Comment: This seems useful. I'm not sure how to fill the inputArray with all of my variables. I have a list of variables with names like variable_1_1, variable_1_2, etc, and need to populate them into the input array somehow but variable_1_ & "n" doesn't work.

Comment: I just updated the question with a more concrete example since I don't think I worded it very well initially.